# Using Azure Active Directory - one application to login locally and when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I'm building an MVC application with Azure Active Directory authentication. When I develop locally I would like to be able to sign-in for testing/development purposes. And the app url is like `http://localhost:43400`. This is also encoded in the AD application in `Sign-On Url` and `Reply Url`.

When I deploy the same app to the server, the app url is changed - becomes something like `myappname.azurewebsites.net` and I can't login using the same AD application. The best I could manage is to get through login process, but then AD redirects me back to `localhost:43400` which is wrong.

There is `PostLogoutRedirectUri` property in `Startup.Auth.cs` that I give to the app, but it makes no difference at all.

**Any way to have local application and deployed application using the same Azure AD?**

I can do 2 AD Applicaitons with different urls and keys and rewrite the values in `web.config` on deploy. But that does not sound like the best solution. Anything else I can do?

**UPD**

Here is the bit I'm referring to in `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri, // <-- this is coming from web.config, different in dev and prod

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            .....

        }
    });
```

See full code listing [here](https://gist.github.com/trailmax/c782ae9a69ac76ae6eb1).

And in Azure AD application I tried both addresses as a Reply URL at the same time:
[image: Azure AD Application Reply URL]

But the AD used only one of the addresses to redirect, even though the client specified the redirection that matches one of the records.

Comment: Can't you create 2 separate applications in that Azure AD?

Comment: I can - that's what my last part of the question say. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry ... didn't read that part! Another thing you could do is have redirect URIs for both environment in the same application. What I have tried is multiple redirect URIs for same environment (one for sign up and other for sign in) in my application but you could give it a try.

Comment: We use WS-Federation and specify a replyUrl in our Web.config WIF-section, which works fine when also configured in the Azure Management Portal.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have tried to specify 2 Reply URL, and then the client to have matching `PostLogoutRedirectUri` and no luck. See update to the question with a bit more code

Comment: @Biscuits maybe I'm providing the replyUrl in the wrong place, but I'm working with the template built by VS when I asked for AD integration. See update to the Q with a bit more code.

Comment: No, replyUrl is off topic because you're using OAuth not WS-Federation. I don't know OAuth too well, but it seems that OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.RedirectUri might be the thing you're looking for. You can assign this to a different value for every environment which should tell Azure where to send the user after logging in (as long as it's one of the URLs configured in the list, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add multiple redirect uri to your app, that's why the property is implemented as a list! You just need to make sure that you specify which URI to use at runtime. You can do that in many ways - you can specify the return URI at middleware init time, or you can add dynamic code that will inject a redirect URI in the sign in message. For an example of the latter approach, please see RedirectToIdentityProvider in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Comment: I have tried to list both addresses in that list, but probably did find a way to specify which one I need. In that code sample, are you talking about `RedirectToIdentityProvider` part? Btw, I've added a bit more code into the question.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to RedirectToIdentityProvider. That will allow you to have a single adaptive codebase that injects the right redirect URI at run time. As I also hinted: if you prefer to change a static string right before deployment, you can always specify which one of the two URI you want to use directly in the middleware initialization, you just pass RedirectUri in the same way in which you pass PostLogoutRedirectUri today.

Comment: Got you! I'll give it a go tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: `RedirectToIdentityProvider` bit worked. Only had to add a forward slash to the url generated in the sample, as I had auth exceptions about domain names not matching. Thanks!