# How can I debug an ASP MVC Webapp in visual studio when using azure active directory authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP MVC app that I am working on in Visual Studio 2015 that uses Azure Active Directory authentication to sign users in.

My issue is that when I go into the debugging mode in Visual Studio, the app starts up and begins the authentication process. But once I am authenticated, I am redirected to the live web app. I have realized that this is happening because the Azure AD authentication service redirects to the live URL. But this means that I am unable to test the app locally without publishing it.

I have tried to figure out a way to change the setting in web.config to allow a local redirect but I am not sure how to do it since the Azure AD always redirects to the live version of the website rather than localhost://12345.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485302/using-azure-active-directory-one-application-to-login-locally-and-when-publish

Comment: Yes! that was my exact problem too, thank you for the pointer.